# Friend class accessing protected member only C++

Tags: c++, friend

```
class A;

class B {
private:
    int x = 3;
protected:
    int y = 4;
public:
    int k = 5;
};
```

I would like `A` to be able to access `B`'s `public` and `protected` members, but not its `private` members.

I do not want `A` to derive from `B`.

-In my program, I have class `A` which manipulates class `B`. I have built a system using these two classes, and thus `B` should only be able to manipulate `A`'s `private` variables through `A`'s `protected` functions.

What is the most elegant way to do this? Is it good practice to lay expose the variables in such a way?

Comment: Why don't you want to derive `A` from `B` ? Thats exactly the function `protected` member access is meant for

Comment: @Odysseus but then every `A` instance would be a `B` instance. There can be a lot of reasons why that is not desirable.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Surely, there's a better way to model the system you're trying to model without awkwardly coupling the two classes. C++ provides two ways to couple classes: inheritance (B really is an A and thus gets to see it all) and friendship (A trusts B completely). Even both of those should be used sparingly (tight coupling), and more complicated visibility constraints like this will likely only serve to confuse.

Comment: @Miguel Yes - but it still is the purpose of `protected`. So rearranging the classes seems reasonable for me

Comment: @Odysseus A mammal could derive from a respiratory system class; this does not mean that the mammal itself is a respiratory system

Comment: @Odysseus Yes, the purpose of `protected` is to provide access to child classes, but that is not a reason to make a class inherit from another just to gain access. That is just bad design and the reason why `friend` exists.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to take advantage of the non-associativity of friends relationships. If you contain the private members of `B` in another class and make `B` its friend, it would work.

Here's an example of what I say.

```
class B{
    private:
        class private_of_B{
        private:
            friend class B;
            int x = 3;
        };
        private_of_B private_members;
        friend class A;
    
    protected:
        int y = 4;
    
    public:
        int k = 5;
};
class A{
    public:
        void f(B& b) const{
            cout << b.y << endl;
            // good
            cout << b.k << endl;
            // good
            cout << b.private_members.x << endl;
            // error
        }
};
```

Anyways, this workaround seems like bad design... maybe the best thing you can do is redesign your class architecture.

Also, you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055616/allowing-a-friend-class-to-access-only-some-private-members) useful.

Comment: The base class super_B is a member of the class B. So the class A is able to access the member of an object of the class B.

Comment: `super_B` is not a member of `B`, it's its parent class, so the class `A` is not allowed to access any  non-public member of it.

Comment: Run this program. #include <iostream>

class A;

class super_B{
protected:
    int x = 3;
};

class B: public super_B{
protected:
    friend class A;
    int y = 4;
public:
    int k = 5;
};

class A
{
public:
 void f( const B &b ) const
 {
  std::cout << b.x << '\n';
 }
};

int main() 
{
 B b;
 
 A().f( b );
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: I changed the answer and tested it, so it works now. But as I say, I would recommend some redesign.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change B, you can create a sort of a proxy class:

```
class B {
private:   
  int x = 3;
protected: 
  int y = 4;
public:    
  int k = 5;
};

class C : public B {
  friend class C_Proxy;
  // constructors...
};

class C_Proxy {
public:
  friend class A;
  C_Proxy(C& c) : y(c.y), k(c.k) { }
private:
  int& y;
  int& k;
}
```

(You can also arrange C_Proxy to handle proxying constant B's but that's not the focus of the question.)