# Is it possible to implement the [] operator twice?

Tags: c++, class, object, operator-overloading

Is it possible to implement something like a double `[]`, in order to call a method of my object like this: `obj[x][y]`?

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994488/what-is-proxy-class-in-c)

Comment: See [C++ FAQ - How do I create a subscript operator](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You can have the regular class operator[] return a special "proxy object" which has its own operator[] to return the final values.

Comment: That is a great idea! Do you know any code examples by any chance?

Comment: I think I found a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload